# How do I perform query in django templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have Two Modeks, Employee Type and Employees:

```
class EmployeeType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    emptype = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Type')
    male = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Male', default=0)
    female = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Female', default=0)
    others = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Others', default=0)
```

This is the relevant view from my forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Employee
    exclude = ('date',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['emptype'].widget.attrs = {'class':'form-control'}
        self.fields['male'].widget.attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Male'}
        self.fields['female'].widget.attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Female'}
        self.fields['others'].widget.attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Others'}
```

and here is views.py:

```
def addEmployee(request):
    employee = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
    'employees':employee,
    }
    return render(request,'add_employee.html',context)
```

and here is my add_employee.html

```
<div class="form-group">

          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Male</th>
                <th scope="col">Female</th>
                <th scope="col">Others</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for em in employees.emptype %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{em}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="male_{{em.id}}" step="any" required="" id="id_male" class="form-control" value="0" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="female_{{em.id}}" step="any" required="" id="id_female" class="form-control" value="0" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="others_{{em.id}}" step="any" required="" id="id_others" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Now I am facing problem in getting EmployeeType ID in name field i.e. {{em.id}}. How I can fix this?

Comment: You *don't*. Please do *not* make queries in the template. A template is supposed to implement *rendering* logic, not *business* logic.

Comment: What if you use `{{ em.type }}` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can overrides the default name of the objects of this class by using **str** method inside the model to show the whatever name you want.

```
 class EmployeeType(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     enable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

     def __str__(self):
       return self.type
```

this way the context will show whatever name is defined in the method or you can user the context_name.field_name which in you case is {{em.type}}